# Copy dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code to copy dynamic range. The Rows look like below :

```
R1 - Title
R2 - Headers
R3 - Data 
R97 - Data

R98 - Blank
R99 - Text
R100 - Title
R101 - Headers
R102 - Data

R150 - Blank
R151 - Text
R153 - Title
R153 - Headers
R154 - Data
```

I have a similar set of data in rows below further. I can't filter and copy because the header is only in 2 cells and there are blank rows in between. Note the columns are static here

I am looking for help to copy the data in a structured format.

I could find the below code in other conversation, which does copy only 2 rows below headers but doesn't ignore the blanks

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim vR(), n As Long, k As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("Trial Balance Detail") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
        '.Columns("e").ClearContents
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A
        Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

        ' loop through all cells in column A and copy below's cell to sheet "Output_2"
        For Each c In rng
            If c.Value = "Jrnl No." Then
                For j = 1 To 2
                    n = n + 1
                    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 13, 1 To n)
                    For k = 1 To 13
                        vR(k, n) = c.Offset(j, k - 1) ' use offset to put value in sheet "Output_2", column E
                    Next k
                Next j
            End If
        Next c
        If n > 0 Then
            Set Ws = Sheets.Add '<~~~  Sheets("your sheet name")
            With Ws
                .Range("a1").Resize(n, 13) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it is unclear what your desired result is. Please take the time to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I need all the rows which has data in tabular format, with only one header at the top. Hope I am clear now

Comment: `.end(xlDown)` or `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` would be where i'd start